# Как управлять позицией объекта с помощью jQuery?

Tags: html, jquery, css

Привет.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Есть пять блоков, все разной ширины. Нужно в зависимости от данных из бд ставить треугольники. Из бд будет передаваться число от 0 до 100. Если будет 50 то треугольники должны быть по средине этих блоков, 0 - слева, 100 - справа. Вообщем в зависимости от числа. Но как это реализовать через jQuery? Именно установка треугольника, а не взятия числа из бд. Дело в том, что ширина div`a где находятся блоки не 100px, а 438px. Да и как разместить треугольники чтобы из-за них не ломалась вся верстка?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну так отмасштабируйте значение

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  var setPos = function(val) {
    var width = $('.block').width();
    $('.pointer').each(function() {
      $(this).css(
        {left: width * val / 100 - $('span', this).width() / 2}
      );
    });
  };
  
  $('input').on('input', function() {
    var val = $(this).val();
    $('.val').text(val);
    setPos(val);
  }).trigger('input');
});
```

```css
.block {
  width: 438px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.pointer {
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="pointer"><span>\/</span></div>
<div class="block">&nbsp;</div>
<div class="pointer"><span>/\</span></div>
<input type="range" min="0" max="100" value="50" /><span class="val"></span>
```

Comment: Шикарно... Спасибо!

Comment: что-то не получается в мой код экспортировать, можно ли как-то просто создать переменную и в зависимости от нее уже ставить pointer, без input range.

Comment: @xomem Вот же Ваша переменная `var val = $(this).val();`. Когда она меняется - меняйте стили для указателей. Для наглядности вынес в отдельную функцию